# Extjs, Font Awesome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I have some image like this..

```
 <img class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   icon-edit action-collumn" src="{data}" alt="" role="button">
```

With chrome work ok! but firefox not showing my icon.

somebody have this same problem?

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    width: 50,
    items: [{
        iconCls: 'icon-edit action-collumn',
        margin: '0 0 0 50',
        handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
            me.onEditRecordClick(rec.get('id'));
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: there is a image component provided in extjs right? why are you using this then?

Comment: have this on my property =>  {
                    xtype:'actioncolumn',
                    width:50,
                    items: [
                        {
                            iconCls: 'icon-edit action-collumn',
                            margin:'0 0 0 50',
                            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                                me.onEditRecordClick(rec.get('id'));
                            }
                        }

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but even in chrome the icon is not shown.